# Test the @ ParameterizedTest annotation method of junit5 through the console. How should I specify methodParameterTypes on the command line?

Tags: console, junit5

Test code:

```
public class TestJunit5 {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = {100,200,300})
    public void test03(int a){
      System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

My command line
`java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar -cp ./target/ --m  basic.step03.TestJunit5#test03('int') --details=none`

Error parsing command-line arguments: Unmatched argument at index 4: 'int'

Comment: Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: MethodSelector [className = 'basic.step03.TestJunit5', methodName = 'test03', methodParameterTypes = ''] resolution failed        
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes around „int“?